Causal Discovery Packages Supporting Mixed Data Types and Prior Knowledge
I am new to the field of Causal Discovery and would like to apply standard algorithms to my dataset, which contains both categorical and continuous variables. I am looking for Python packages that can handle mixed data types and incorporate prior knowledge. However, I have observed that most existing Python packages for Causal Discovery do not inherently support mixed data.
First, for constraint-based methods like PC Algorithm, the Causal-Learn package only supports one type of conditional independence test.
Constraint-based methods: The Causal-Learn package, which implements the PC Algorithm, seems to support only one type of conditional independence test. This limitation might pose challenges when working with mixed data.
Structural equation models (SEM): Many methods in the LiNGAM series assume continuous noise, which might make them unsuitable for datasets containing discrete variables (please correct me if I’m wrong). While the LiNGAM package does provide methods like LiM for mixed data types, it appears that these methods do not support the inclusion of prior knowledge.

How big is your dataset in question? Have you checked out CausalNex?

Hi, Thank you for your suggestion! I have two datasets. One has 13 columns and 500 rows, another has 30 columns and 500 rows. I went over the website, the structure learning part adopts NOTEARS algorithm and was able to add prior knowledge, but NOTEARS accepts numerical values only. As for Bayesian Network part, it's unable to add prior knowledge.

If you are new to causal discovery, I'd just like to caution you that most causal discovery algorithms come with strong assumptions that are unlikely to be met in many real datasets, and their results on synthetic data may thus not replicate.
For an example: the MSE-loss used by NOTEARS is not scale-invariant, meaning that if you multiply a variable by a constant, the results may change. Now consider that data scales are typically arbitrary (why should measuring a distance in miles vs. meters change causal relationships?) and you will see the problem...

Hi, gotcha! Thank you!
